# Doing a binary classification using xgboost, getting a 10000x2 yhat

Tags: python, classification, xgboost

I am new to xgboost and I am trying to run a model for binary classification.

```
import pandas as pd

import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier


df_train = pd.read_csv('case2_training.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('case2_testing.csv')
df_train.shape, df_test.shape

# Exam the data
print(df_train.head())
print(df_test.head())

# Check for exsitence of null
df_train.info()

print('--------------------------------------------------------------')

X, y = df_train.iloc[:, :-1], df_train.iloc[:, -1]  # X = features Y = label

data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X, label=y)
# Split the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)


xgb = XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster=None, colsample_bylevel=1,
                    colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=0.5, gamma=0, gpu_id=-1,
                    importance_type='gain', interaction_constraints=None,
                    learning_rate=0.3, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=6,
                    min_child_weight=1,  monotone_constraints=None,
                    n_estimators=25, n_jobs=0, num_parallel_tree=1,
                    objective='binary:logistic', random_state=0, reg_alpha=0,
                    reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=None, seed=0, subsample=0.5,
                    tree_method=None, validate_parameters=False, verbosity=None)
xgb.fit(X_train,y_train)

yhat = xgb.predict_proba(X_test)

print(yhat.shape)
print(yhat)
print(y_test.shape)
# train_accuracy = roc_auc_score(y_test, yhat)
```

The yhat here gave a (10000x2) which is not what I expected. It should be 10000x1 and then I can round them off to compare with the y_test.
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get probabilities of a given class for each of your data points. So sum of two numbers in columns = 1, and you can find the class by taking `np.argmax()`.

Comment: Yes you were correct, I changed predict_prob to predict and it worked. However, the AUC is only 0.6, i cannot improve it much by changing the parameters. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Improving accuracy of a particular classifier is a very broad question. I suggest you start by running automated parameter tuning using GridSeachCV from scikit-learn package. If you are not satisfied with those results, try asking another question with best result you get from parameter tuning.

Comment: Thank you.The bad news is that, a strange error occurred 2 mins ago. All my sk module cannot be found...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model'; 'sklearn' is not a package